# Is it possible to call web service method with less parameters through SoapUI tool

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

I am testing a SOAP web service through SoapUI tool. Web Service is deployed on a server and SaopUI project is hitting that web service. My concern is while testing one request if I do not provide a mandatory input parameter even then I am getting successful response. No error at all. On the other hand, if we call the same through web application then error comes.

WSDL request:

```
<wsdl:message name="update_request">
     <wsdl:part name="name" type="xsd:boolean"></wsdl:part>
     <wsdl:part name="flag" type="xsd:boolean"></wsdl:part> 
</wsdl:message>
```

Is it possible to call a request with less parameters through SoapUI? Why there is a difference between these two calling methods?

Answer (score 0):

Using the XML view of a `Test Request` test step in soapUI you can freely edit what shall be sent.

Example:

```
<soap...>
  <MyUpdateRequest>
    <name>true</name>
  </MyUpdateRequest>
</soap...>
```

Comment: You mean to say I can sent the above request "update_request" with name parameter only. There will be no error in calling with flag parameter as null?

Comment: Yes, I think so. soapUI should send the message as long as the server component providing the webservice accepts this.

Comment: As I have written you can type anything you like. You could also edit the SOAP message to look like `<soap>HelloWorld</soap>` and send it.